# Lookup a value and use formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the below table information and I need to lookup a value and then use a formula:

[image: Table Info]

Columns A, B and C is my lookup table. Column E is the value I want to lookup  and column F is the result of the formula.

F2 has the correct formula and the result but it's done by specifying the cells rather than using a vlookup. There are a lot of values I need to lookup so specifying the cells is not practical. Sometimes the value i'm looking for is in 3 rows, sometimes it's 2 etc

I tried the below formula and the result is shown in F3 but it's not correct. Anyone knows how I can achieve the same result in F2 by using a lookup formula?

Formula used (My failed attempt):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(E3,$A$2:$C$10,{2},FALSE))
```

Formula used in F2 (correct result but I specified the cells here)

```
=SUM(B2:B4*C2:C4) / SUM(B2:B4)
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$10,$B$2:$B$10,--($A$2:$A$10=E2))/SUMIFS($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10,E2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that, and it returned '#NAME?'

Comment: @SAJ I had a typo.  see edit.

Comment: I just tried that, and it works perfectly. Thanks :)